# Showing two layers at same time in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, layers, attribute-joins, line

I want to see two QGIS layers at the same time.

one is lines which are boundary lines and the other is polygon which are district.

when i was surfing about this question, it is impossible to show two layers with different type.

Comment: If you load both layers and put the line layer on top of the polygon layer, you should see both. If not, please add screenshots so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Are your layers defined in the same or different CRS?  If different you will have to check the "Enable on the fly CRS transformation" check box under the Project menu>Project Properties>CRS tab.

Comment: oh thanks , I check the "Enable on the fly CRS transformation".
then, the problems what concerned me are solved